# Vector space $V = \Bbb{R}^4$ with the Sub-spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Vector space $V =  \Bbb{R}^4$ with the Sub-spaces

$W_1=${$(x,x+y,x+z,z)|x,y,z \in \Bbb{R}$}

$W_2=${$(a,b,a,b)|a,b \in \Bbb{R}$}

choose one of the following:

1. $W_1+W_2=V$ and $W_1\cap\ W_2 = ${0}
2. $W_1+W_2=V$ but $W_1\cap\ W_2 \neq ${0}

The answer is 2, but I can't find $W_1$ and $W_2$ that make the answer correct, I found $(1,0,1,0)$ to work for the $\cap$ but they don't make $V$, and I don't understand why the answer isn't 1.

Thanks.

Comment: This is the same question as yesterday. Don't do this. What have you tried in the meantime? Did you write down what $v\in W_1$ and $v\in W:_2$ means? Then it is clear what $W_1\cap W_2$ is.

Comment: I don't understand how it spans $V$
How does (1,0,1,0)+(1,0,1,0) = $V$

Comment: Why are you so focused on trying to humiliate me instead of helping me...
I wrote everything that I have tried already...
I would have not posted this question here if I knew how to solve it or found someone from my course that could give me an answer that would be satisfying enough.....
$W_1 \cap W_2$ is the cross section between them.

Comment: You seem to think $W_1+W_2$ as the set of sum of vectors from $W_1\cap W_2$, which is nonsense. Instead, it consists of $w_1+w_2$ where $w_1$ runs through *all* $W_1$ and independently $w_2$ runs through all $W_2$. Can you rephrase the restriction for a vector $(a,b,c,d)$ to be in $W_1$?

Comment: must make this? {$(x,x+y,x+z,z)|x,y,z \in \Bbb{R}$} 

a,b,c,d $\in \Bbb{R}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We get the following vectors in $W_1$: $u_1=(1,1,1,0),\ u_2=(0,1,0,0),\ u_3=(0,0,1,1)$ and all their linear combinations.

Similarly for $W_2$: $v_1=(1,0,1,0),\ v_2=(0,1,0,1)$.

$W_1+W_2$ contains all the linear combinations of $u_1,u_2,u_3,v_1,v_2$.

Can you express all 4 standard basis vectors $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$ with them? (E.g. $e_2=u_2$ is already expressed, $e_4=v_2-u_2$, etc.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I now understand my mistake... and what you said was nonsense, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Any vector of $W_1$ with $z=0$ and $x=-y$ is also an element of $W_2$.

Comment: I know this already, I don't understand how $W_1 + W_2 = V$ is understood out of what you've just written